# Jest mock not working when any transformer is configuration

Tags: mocking, jestjs

When add any transformer or empty property transform to Jest config, mocks are not working. Simple code below.

Jest config:

```
"transform": {
any regex: any transformer
}
```

Module say:

```
module.exports = (m) => {
    console.log(m);
};
```

Module test-module:

```
const say = require("./say");

module.exports = () => {
    say("Hello world!");
};
```

Test:

```
jest.mock("./say", () => () => console.log("Mock!!!!"));

test("any test", () => {
});
```

If delete transform config, mock works, will get message: Mock!!!!.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding transformations removes the default.

Adding `'.*': 'babel-jest'` as a fallback resolved this for me.

```
transform: {
  '\\.xml$': 'jest-raw-loader',
  '.*': 'babel-jest',
},
```

Related issues

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2076
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8574